# Do I have to restart colaboratory runtime every time?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I cannot run my code in Google Colaboratory twice without restarting runtime. Is there a way to run it without restarting runtime.

My code takes TensorD libraries and compute aproximation of a random 2x4x4 tensor using CP ALS algorithm. (this is an example taken from https://github.com/Large-Scale-Tensor-Decomposition/tensorD)

```
!git clone https://github.com/Large-Scale-Tensor-Decomposition/tensorD.git
import sys
import time
sys.path.append("/content/tensorD")

from tensorD.factorization.env import Environment
from tensorD.dataproc.provider import Provider
from tensorD.demo.DataGenerator import *
from tensorD.factorization.cp import CP_ALS

# generate a random tensor with shape 3x4x4
t = time.time()
X = synthetic_data_cp([3, 4, 4], 7)
data_provider = Provider()
data_provider.full_tensor = lambda: X
env = Environment(data_provider, summary_path='/tmp/cp_' + '7')
cp = CP_ALS(env)
args = CP_ALS.CP_Args(rank=7, validation_internal=1)
# build CP model with arguments
cp.build_model(args)
# train CP model with the maximum iteration of 100
cp.train(50)
# obtain factor matrices from trained model
factor_matrices = cp.factors
# obtain scaling vector from trained model
lambdas = cp.lambdas
for matrix in factor_matrices:
    print(matrix)

elapsed = time.time() - t
print(elapsed)
```

when I run it first time I have no problem. When I run it again (without restart of runtime) I obtain:

```
CP model initial finish

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

7 frames

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [3,4,4]
     [[{{node Placeholder}}]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1346           pass
   1347       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1348       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1349 
   1350   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [3,4,4]
     [[node Placeholder (defined at /content/tensorD/tensorD/factorization/cp.py:69) ]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-4d2250ec007b>", line 21, in <module>
    cp.build_model(args)
  File "/content/tensorD/tensorD/factorization/cp.py", line 69, in build_model
    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=self._env.full_shape())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2077, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 5791, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [3,4,4]
     [[node Placeholder (defined at /content/tensorD/tensorD/factorization/cp.py:69) ]]
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to mostly be a question about TensorFlow. Do you get what you want outside of Colab? I'm not totally clear about what you are expecting, but `import tensorflow as tf; tf.reset_default_graph()` at the top of your snippet seems sensible and squelches the error.